# Android Naming a SKU

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, release, in-app-billing, sku

For my testing I used:

```
private static final String SKU_PRO = "android.test.purchased";
```

Now I want to release my app and create the purchasable item in the developer console. Before releasing the apk I have to know how to name the SKU.
In a tutorial I read they used this:

```
"com.example.buttonclick"
```

But my packagename looks like this:

```
"com.myname.myapp"
```

My suggestion is:

```
"com.myname.myapp.purchasedpro"
```

Is this the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html):

> **Product ID**
>
> Product IDs are unique across an app's namespace. A product
> ID must start with a lowercase letter or a number and must be composed
> of only lowercase letters (a-z), numbers (0-9), underscores (_), and
> periods (.). The product ID android.test is reserved, as are all
> product IDs that start with android.test.
>
> **Note**: Be sure to plan your
> product ID namespace carefully. You cannot modify an item's product ID
> after the item is created, and you cannot reuse a product ID within an
> app.

Comment: so it makes no difference as long it is an unique identifier in the app .